# Proof finite dimensional equaltiy implies equality on interval

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Consider the stochastic process $\{X(t)\}_{t\in T}$ and certain specific operations $g$ and $f$. If $T$ is of finite dimension, i.e. $T=\{t_1,\ldots,t_k\}$, with $t_i\in 0,\infty)$ then I have been able to proof that the two operation coincide
$$g(X(t))=f(X(t)), \ t\in T.$$

I am now looking to extend this result to $T=[0,\infty)$.

Does anyone know how to go about this? I am also looking for good references on this topic.

Comment: "...then I have been able to proof that the two operation coincide..." From what *hypothesis* have you been able to prove this?

Comment: For some specific operations only.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? What sort of $f$ and $g$ do you have in mind? Is $X$ a general stochastic process, or does it enjoy any special properties? As it stands right now, your question is too vague to properly address.